# How to designate a Rack handler

Tags: ruby, cgi, webserver, rack

**Rackup** is successfully running any **Rack** app via Rack's default handler. e.g.:

```rb
class RackApp  
  def call(environment)    
  [
    '200', 
    {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, 
    ["Hello world"]
  ]
  end 
end
run RackApp.new
```

But rackup is giving "NoMethodError at / undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass" when the last line is changed to instead use Rack's built-in CGI handler:

```
Rack::Handler::CGI.run RackApp.new
```

The same objection is raised for Rack's other built-in handlers. e.g. Rack::Handler::Thin, Rack::Handler::FastCGI, even Rack::Handler::WEBrick (which is the handler Rack selects above in default mode).

What's the correct syntax here?

Comment: I am surprised the sample runs as there is no method run, so `run RackApp.new` will return an undefined method error.  The CGI Handler on the other hand will work fine.

Comment: It's being executed by rackup, i.e.<code>$ rackup rackapp.ru</code>.  So run does exist; and, as I noted, runs as expected.  It's the Rack::Handler::foo.run methods that seem to be missing.  Explicit require of 'rack', 'rack/handler', and 'rack/handler/foo' don't seem to get rackup recognizing them either.

Answer (score 8):

The `rackup` command reads the config file and starts a server. The `Rack::Handler::XXX.run` methods *also* start a server, independently of the `rackup` command (`CGI` is slightly different as it isn't actually a server as such).

What happens when you change the line

```
run RackApp.new
```

to

```
Rack::Handler::CGI.run RackApp.new
```

and run `rackup` is as follows. The server starts and parses the config file. When the `Rack::Handler::CGI.run RackApp.new` line is reached it is executed as any other Ruby code would be. In the case of the CGI handler this calls the app and writes the output to the standard output as it would if running as a CGI script (have a look at your terminal when you run `rackup`). Afterwards the 'rackup' server is started as normal, but without an app to run. When you try to access the page you'll get the NoMethodError, since the app is nil.

Using `Rack::Handler::Thin` is similar, but in this case, as Thin actually is a web server, it is started and will serve `RackApp`, but listens on Thin's default port of 8080 (not the rack default of 9292). After stopping Thin (e.g. with Ctrl-C) the default rackup server (Mongrel or Webrick) will start listening on port 9292, again with no app specified so you'll get the NoMethodError.

If you run your modified 'config.ru' as a plain Ruby script rather than using rackup you'll see the same behaviour, but without the rackup server being started. (You'll need to require rack first, so use `ruby -rrack config.ru`). In the CGI case the output of a single call to your app will be printed to the console, in the Thin case Thin will be started serving your app.

In order to specify the server to use with rackup, you can use the `-s` option, e.g. `rackup -s thin` will start the app using Thin (this time on the rackup default port of 9292). You can also do `rackup -s cgi` but this won't really work in any useful way - it just prints out the html of an error page to the console.

### CGI

If you're trying to run your app as a CGI there are a couple of options. You need to create a CGI script that calls your app using the CGI handler. This could itself be a ruby script that calls `Rack::Handler::CGI.run` directly, in fact you could use your modified `config.ru` directly (you might want to rename it first and add an explicit `require 'rack'` line).

Alternatively you can use a shell script which then calls `rackup config.ru`. In this situation rackup detects that it's running as CGI and automatically uses the correct handler

Comment: You've said "The rackup command reads the config file and starts a server", but: What config file, and where is it documented?

Answer (score 1):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html    (see point 3.5)

also interesting:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware

http://railscasts.com/episodes/222-rack-in-rails-3

Comment: This is not a Rails question, and I'm not looking to create a custom handler, custom dispatcher, or do routing.  Would you elaborate on how any of those answer the question of how to select from among Rack's built in handlers?